# How do I remove a specific div out of many using one function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JavaScript and this is a practice scenario for me.

What I have already is a button that clones content, and within that content that has been cloned, there is a button to remove it.

When I click the button that prompts you to remove the content, it removes the first set of content.

What I want to happen is when you click the button that prompts you to remove the content, it removes the content related to that button and nothing else.

This is the CodePen link.

https://codepen.io/JosephChunta/pen/YzwwgvQ

Here is the code.

```js
function addContent() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("newContent");
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("placeToStoreContent").appendChild(cln);
}

function removeContent() {
  var x = document.getElementById("content").parentNode.remove();
}

// This is for debug purposes to see which content is which
document.getElementById('orderContent')
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const orderedNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.thisIsContent');
    let i = 1;
    for (p of orderedNumber) {
      p.innerText = '' + (i++);
    }
  });
```

```css
.contentThatShouldBeHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeToStoreContent">

</div>

<button id="orderContent" onclick="addContent()">Add Content</button>

<div class="contentThatShouldBeHidden">
  <div id="newContent">
    <div id="content">
      <p class="thisIsContent">This is a prompt</p>
      <button onclick="removeContent()">Remove this</button>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to make use of the `this.` selector so that you get the current selection. If you go by the id selector, it will simply go for the first instance (since id is unique) and then do the remove function on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you'r trying to remove by ID, it takes the first ID it finds.

To remove the correct content, send `this` onclick.

```
  <button onclick="removeContent(this)">Remove this</button>
```

And handle it in your function:

```
function removeContent(el) {
  el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Example:

```js
function addContent() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("newContent");
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("placeToStoreContent").appendChild(cln);
}

function removeContent(el) {
  el.parentNode.remove();
}

// This is for debug purposes to see which content is which
document.getElementById('orderContent')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const orderedNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.thisIsContent');
            let i = 1;
            for (p of orderedNumber) {
                p.innerText = '' + (i++);
            }
        });
```

```css
.contentThatShouldBeHidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="placeToStoreContent">
  
</div>

<button id="orderContent" onclick="addContent()">Add Content</button>

<div class="contentThatShouldBeHidden">
  <div id="newContent">
    <div id="content">
      <p class="thisIsContent">This is a prompt</p>
      <button onclick="removeContent(this)">Remove this</button>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to pass `this`. `this` in the context of `removeContent` will be the element clicked.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? Tried without this in fiddle and it does not seem to work?
https://jsfiddle.net/jsc61m4f/

Answer (score 1):

In your remove button, do this:

```html
<!-- The "this" keyword is a reference to the button element itself -->
<button onclick="removeContent(this)">Remove this</button>
```

And in your javascript:

```js
function removeContent(element) {
  element.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Comment: No need to pass `this`. `this` in the context of `removeContent` will be the element clicked.

Comment: Could you elaborate that? I mean, if I call `this.parentNode.remove()` inside the `removeContent` will it work?

Comment: Yes. Make it `onclick="removeContent()"` and `this.parentNode.remove()`.

Comment: Tried it here. It doesn't seem to work: https://codepen.io/julianobrasil/pen/XWXdKmQ

Comment: In fact  the context here is window. Where the function is called

Comment: The function is supposed to be called in the context of the element when using [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) ("Within the function, `this` will be the element upon which the event was triggered."). I think the `cloneNode` is affecting that.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading comment, but the spec is on my side... :(

Comment: ... all the more reason to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` though. :)

Comment: It's super strange! Even by testing without cloning a node that not working and send window object --> https://codepen.io/jerembardon/pen/BajKzRJ. Problem in spec or ?